# Possible to disable touchscreen before login?

Tags: 18.04, bios, touchscreen, xinput

I installed Linux (currently 18.04 I believe) after wiping Windows off my laptop. Unfortunately, it fell off the couch one too many times and the touchscreen cracked. It's not something I can't overlook, it's not a massive crack. The first time I used it I simply disabled it with xinput and everything was fine. The next time I turned it on however, it had degraded to the point where I couldn't even log in due to it clicking in random places several times a second.

So, my question is, is it possible to disable the touchscreen before I get to the login screen? Some sort of BIOS magic or the like? I really need the data from this computer, I have hundreds of hours of work on there. I'm kinda freaked out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: No panic. Your data are not lost. You'll always have the possibility to extract the disk and mount it elsewhere (for example with an USB to S-ATA adapter cable). BTW if you have hundreds of hours of work on your laptop you should have made backups.

Comment: Oh, great, that's a big relief. I don't know how I didn't even think of that.

And yeah, that was a bit idiotic not to make backups, wasn't it? I think I've learned my lesson now. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you still want to use it, you can try booting into a text console (can be achieved with some kernel boot parameters that I don't remember) or dropping to a root shell from recovery mode (can be selected in grub) and persistently disable the device. I don't think the erroneous touch events will produce symbols in any text-only environment.